# c - why is my for loop with a scanf not being executed?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char firstName1[20];
    char lastName1[20];
    char firstName2[20];
    char lastName2[20];
    char firstName3[20];
    char lastName3[20];


    int scores[18];

    scanf("%s", &firstName1[0]);
    scanf("%s", &lastName1[0]);

    printf("%s ", &firstName1[0]);
    printf("%s ", &lastName1[0]);

    //this for loop here is not being executed, could it be a formatting 
    issue? 
    //%i or %d?
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i>6;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %d ", &scores[i]);
    }


    int j=0;
    for(j=0;j>6;j++)
    {
        printf("%i", &scores{j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The picture provided shows the output result, the taking in name and printing name works but the loop with the scanf to take in scores is not being executed

[The first part of the code taking in the name and printing it back works, however the rest of the code (being the for loops) are not being executed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ufJ3.png)

Answer (score 5):

change

```
 for(i=0;i>6;i++)
```

and

```
 for(j=0;j>6;j++)
```

to

```
 for(i=0;i<6;i++)
```

and

```
 for(j=0;j<6;j++)
```

the loop only runs while the condition is true and at the start `i=0` so `i>6` is false... or in English the way you have written it the loop runs whilst i is greater than 6 - i starts at 0 so it does not run the loop - same issue with your next loop.

There are some other things - like in the first loop I would put in a line to say

```
  printf("please enter score %d: ",i);
```

because then it will make more sense as you enter numbers and you will see what is happening better.

Edited code below....  ** plus note the `&` is only for `scanf` not `printf` ** see in code below it has been removed for the `printf` in the final loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char firstName1[20];
    char lastName1[20];
    char firstName2[20];
    char lastName2[20];
    char firstName3[20];
    char lastName3[20];


    int scores[18];

    scanf("%s", &firstName1[0]);
    scanf("%s", &lastName1[0]);

    printf("%s ", &firstName1[0]);
    printf("%s ", &lastName1[0]);

    //this for loop here is not being executed, could it be a formatting 
    issue? 
    //%i or %d?
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        printf("please enter score %d: ",i);       
        scanf(" %d ", &scores[i]);
    }


    int j=0;
    for(j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
        printf("score %i: %i\n", j, scores{j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did not realize that mistake, thanks! could you also tell me why the scores are being taken in but not printed correctly?
http://tinypic.com/r/2nva5ag/9
(not sure which link will work)
http://oi68.tinypic.com/2nva5ag.jpg

Comment: @William Yes - I should have spotted that - I just edited the answer about that point. - You don't need the `&` when you print out.... the `&` means address of and `scanf` needs it, whereas `printf` just needs the value so last line should be `printf("%i\n", scores{j]);` do put the `\n` gives a newline after each score.

Comment: @tom Consider [Don't ever ask someone to accept your own answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305468/is-it-bad-form-to-ask-a-commentor-for-an-accept-upvote#comment243847_305468)

Comment: @chux - thanks for your message - I didn't realize the ettiquette. I won't do it again - except to ask for people to accept other people's answers to show that their question is solved, but is even that something that one should not do?  p.s. I love your profile picture. -- I am a bit younger perhaps, coding since ZX81